# Is it possible to get the sample distribution $F_X(x)$ out of a second order statistics $F_{X_{(2)}}(x)$?

Tags: order-statistics

If I observe the distribution of the second order statistics $F_{X_{(2)}}(x)$, are there ways to back out the sample distribution $F_X(x)$, such that $F_x(x)$ satisfies the properties of a CDF.

I would say the inversion does not give a unique solution. Are there documented numerical ways (or approximated ones) to back out the family of $F_X(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

One can write $F_{X_{(2)}}(x) = g(F_X(x))$ for a certain polynomial $g$, given in the first displayed equation in a Wikipedia [article's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Cumulative_distribution_function_of_order_statistics) section on the distribution functions of order statistics.  It is not hard to see that the polynomial $g(t)$ is strictly increasing,  $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$.  Hence solving 
$F_{X_{(2)}}(x) = g(F_X(x))$ for $F_X(x)$ given the value of $F_{X_{(2)}}(x)$ should always be possible, but (typically) not in "closed form".

(Note that $g(p)$ is the probability of the event that $Y\ge 2$, where $Y\sim\text{Bin}(n,p)$. Obviously $P(Y=0)=1$ when $p=0$ and $P(Y=n)=1$ when $p=1$, and so on.  A simple coupling  argument can show $g(t)\le g(u)$ if $t<u$.)